# How to color a specific row

Tags: c#, spreadsheetlight

I am first time started working with SpreadsheetLight to export datatable to excel. my objective is to set specific row color. i have tried but no color is coming. issue is not clear to me that where i made the mistake in code. please have a look at my code and tell me what i miss to add in my code.

I create a custom theme for color.

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using SpreadsheetLight;

private SLThemeSettings BuildTheme()
{
    SLThemeSettings theme = new SLThemeSettings();
    theme.ThemeName = "RDSColourTheme";
    //theme.MajorLatinFont = "Impact";
    //theme.MinorLatinFont = "Harrington";
    // this is recommended to be pure white
    theme.Light1Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    // this is recommended to be pure black
    theme.Dark1Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    theme.Light2Color = System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
    theme.Dark2Color = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
    theme.Accent1Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    theme.Accent2Color = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
    theme.Accent3Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    theme.Accent4Color = System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen;
    theme.Accent5Color = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    theme.Accent6Color = System.Drawing.Color.DarkViolet;
    theme.Hyperlink = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    theme.FollowedHyperlinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
    return theme;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("IP Address", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date (UTC)", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("Size (MB)", typeof(double));
    dt.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(decimal));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
    dt.Rows.Add(string.Format("Prod{0}", i+1),
        string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256)),
        DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(rand.NextDouble() * 20),
        decimal.Round((decimal)(rand.NextDouble() * 500 + 200), 4),
        decimal.Round((decimal)(rand.NextDouble() * 20 + 5), 2));
    }

    //SLThemeSettings stSettings = BuildTheme();
    SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();
    sl.ImportDataTable(1, 1, dt, true);

    // This part sets the style, but you might be using a template file,
    // so the styles are probably already set.

    ////setting date format for column 4
    SLStyle style = sl.CreateStyle();
    style.FormatCode = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    sl.SetColumnStyle(3, style);

    //fixed first row and 3 columns from left
    sl.FreezePanes(1, 4);


    //// setting first row color & style
    SLStyle headerstyle = sl.CreateStyle();
    headerstyle.Font.Bold = true;
    //headerstyle.Fill.SetPatternBackgroundColor(PatternValues.Solid, System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed, System.Drawing.Color.Gray);
    //headerstyle.Fill.SetPatternBackgroundColor(SLThemeColorIndexValues.Light2Color);
    //headerstyle.Fill.SetPatternForegroundColor(SLThemeColorIndexValues.Dark2Color);
    sl.SetRowStyle(5,5, headerstyle);

    sl.SaveAs("d:\\Test.xlsx");

    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

This way i tried to add color for first row `headerstyle.Fill.SetPatternBackgroundColor(PatternValues.Solid, System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed, System.Drawing.Color.Gray);` but did not work.

again i tried this way too `headerstyle.Fill.SetPatternForegroundColor(SLThemeColorIndexValues.Dark2Color);` but did not work.

but i set font bold for first row this way `headerstyle.Font.Bold = true;` it worked but color is not applying on first row. where i made the mistake ?

**My openXml version  2.5.5631.0 & SpreadsheetLight version 3.4.9.0**

Please push me to right direction. thanks

### UPDATE

Now issue fixed and working code added here.
        //Install-Package DocumentFormat.OpenXml -Version 2.8.1

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rand = new Random();

    System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Product", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("IP Address", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date (UTC)", typeof(DateTime));
    dt.Columns.Add("Size (MB)", typeof(double));
    dt.Columns.Add("Cost", typeof(decimal));

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(string.Format("Prod{0}", i+1),
            string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256), rand.Next(256)),
            DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(rand.NextDouble() * 20),
            decimal.Round((decimal)(rand.NextDouble() * 500 + 200), 4),
            decimal.Round((decimal)(rand.NextDouble() * 20 + 5), 2));
    }

    SLThemeSettings stSettings = BuildTheme();
    SLDocument sheet = new SLDocument(stSettings);
    sheet.ImportDataTable(1, 1, dt, true);

    //set col width
    sheet.SetColumnWidth(1, 5, 12);

    // This part sets the style, but you might be using a template file,
    // so the styles are probably already set.

    ////setting date format for column 4
    SLStyle style = sheet.CreateStyle();
    style.FormatCode = "MM/dd/yyyy";
    sheet.SetColumnStyle(3, style);

    //fixed first row and 3 columns from left
    sheet.FreezePanes(1, 4);

    //// setting first row color & style
    SLStyle headerstyle = sheet.CreateStyle();
    headerstyle.Font.Bold = true;
    headerstyle.Font.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
    headerstyle.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Light2Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Light2Color);
    sheet.SetRowStyle(1, headerstyle);

    //// setting first row color & style for red color section
    SLStyle redrowstyle = sheet.CreateStyle();
    redrowstyle.Font.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    redrowstyle.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent1Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent1Color);
    sheet.SetCellStyle("A9", "E15", redrowstyle);

    //// setting first row color & style for yellow color section
    SLStyle yellowrowstyle = sheet.CreateStyle();
    redrowstyle.Font.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    redrowstyle.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent3Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent3Color);
    sheet.SetCellStyle("A16", "E18", redrowstyle);

    //// setting a specifc cell color & style
    SLStyle cellstyle = sheet.CreateStyle();
    cellstyle.Font.FontColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    cellstyle.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent4Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent4Color);
    sheet.SetCellStyle("A19", cellstyle);

    //standard number format
    SLStyle standardstyle = new SLStyle();
    standardstyle.FormatCode = "#,##0.000;[Red](-#,##0.000);#,##0.000";
    sheet.SetCellStyle("D1", "D4", standardstyle);

    //CurrencySign number format
    SLStyle CurrencySignstyle = new SLStyle();
    CurrencySignstyle.FormatCode = "$#,##0.000;[Red]$(-#,##0.000);$#,##0.000";
    sheet.SetCellStyle("D5", "D6", CurrencySignstyle);

    //PercentageSign number format
    SLStyle PercentageSignstyle = new SLStyle();
    PercentageSignstyle.FormatCode = "0.00%;[Red](-0.00%);0.00%";
    sheet.SetCellStyle("D7", "D10", PercentageSignstyle);

    sheet.SaveAs("d:\\SpreadsheetLight.xlsx");
    MessageBox.Show("Done");
}

private SLThemeSettings BuildTheme()
{
    SLThemeSettings theme = new SLThemeSettings();
    theme.ThemeName = "RDSColourTheme";
    //theme.MajorLatinFont = "Impact";
    //theme.MinorLatinFont = "Harrington";
    // this is recommended to be pure white
    theme.Light1Color = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    // this is recommended to be pure black
    theme.Dark1Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
    theme.Light2Color = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
    theme.Dark2Color = System.Drawing.Color.IndianRed;
    theme.Accent1Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    theme.Accent2Color = System.Drawing.Color.Tomato;
    theme.Accent3Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
    theme.Accent4Color = System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen;
    theme.Accent5Color = System.Drawing.Color.DeepSkyBlue;
    theme.Accent6Color = System.Drawing.Color.DarkViolet;
    theme.Hyperlink = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
    theme.FollowedHyperlinkColor = System.Drawing.Color.Purple;
    return theme;
}

// read cell value from excel file in for loop
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var sheet = new SLDocument(@"d:\SpreadsheetLight.xlsx");
    SLWorksheetStatistics stats = sheet.GetWorksheetStatistics();

    for (int row = 2; row < stats.EndRowIndex; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 1; col < stats.EndColumnIndex; col++)
        {
            // Get the first column of the row (SLS is a 1-based index)
            var value = sheet.GetCellValueAsString(row, col);
            MessageBox.Show(value);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to documentation you should be calling:

```
headerstyle.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.LightTrellis, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent1Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent2Color);
```

Here's an example:

```
SLDocument sl = new SLDocument();

SLStyle style1 = sl.CreateStyle();
style1.Fill.SetPattern(PatternValues.Solid, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent2Color, SLThemeColorIndexValues.Accent4Color);

// set row 4 with 1st style
sl.SetRowStyle(4, style1);
sl.SaveAs("StyleRowColumnCell.xlsx");
```

I extracted this sample from [this example](http://spreadsheetlight.com/downloads/samplecode/StyleRowColumnCell.cs) from their website.

Comment: i test your code but i saw foreground color has no effect. suppose i was trying to set row back color gray and fore color red but fail. not being able to set 1st row's all cell text color red.

Comment: Now issue sorted. i found text color has to set by font color. my working code updated in my post. thanks for your reply.